# Creating tiled pyramidal TIFF from PNG tiles that are organized in slippy map?

Tags: geotiff-tiff, convert, tiles, offline, image-pyramids

I have map tiles (Z/X/Y) of a certain location which I serve via a simple web server and add on QGIS for offline usage via the XYZ Tile Layer from the Browse menu.

These are to be used in a survey of a remote area that doesn't have Internet connectivity. However, moving these tiles from device to device takes time and I was wondering if I could convert them to a pyramidal tiled TIFF file which would admittedly be a large file but will be simple to move around and also to add to QGIS (as a raster layer).

It is also more amenable to land analysis.

I have looked at various libraries such as `libtiff`, etc but most seem capable of going the other way (from one large raster TIFF to XYZ tiles).

What I need to do is put the tiles of each zoom layer into one layer of the image pyramid. Each layer should be a tiled layer.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?